# Какого типа массивы в Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Массивы в Java - объекты. Но какого они типа (класса)?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8

Comment: для какой цели вы спрашиваете? какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Для всеобщего развития. Просто и в учебниках написано что массив это обьект и даже свойство размер он имеит. только в java он имеит специфичный синтаксис создания и обращения с ним. ибо как таковых методов нет и все обращения через []

Answer (score 7):

У каждого массива есть свой класс (тип). Массивы одного типа имеют один и тот же класс.

```
int a[]; 
int b[]; // класс такой же как у a

byte c[]; // другой класс, не такой как у a или b
```

Все массивы являются наследниками **Object** и реализуют интерфейсы **Cloneable** и **Serializable**

Вот ссылка на [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) и конкретно на раздел [10.8. Class Objects for Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8)